# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException ERROR

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Intento correr mi aplicación en *NetBeans* y me sale el siguiente error.

Mi error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'BDEncuesta' defined in file [D:\adenbpo-reportes-encuestas-ms\target\classes\com\adenbpo\BDEncuesta.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.adenbpo.BDEncuesta] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:550) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.adenbpo.AdenbpoReportesEncuestasApplication.main(AdenbpoReportesEncuestasApplication.java:40) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.adenbpo.BDEncuesta] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:758) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:690) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:411) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:395) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-orm-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1013) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/adenbpo/conf/BDEncuestaConf;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:753) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adenbpo.conf.BDEncuestaConf
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Mi archivo POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <version.adenbpo.encuestas.repository>1.0</version.adenbpo.encuestas.repository>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!--                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.adenbpo.AdenbpoReportesEncuestasApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Este es el archivo *BDEncuesta.class*

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
@DependsOn(ConfigurationBD.NAME_TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = BDEncuestaConf.BASE_PACKAGES_REPOSITORY,
        entityManagerFactoryRef = BDEncuestaConf.NAME_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY,
        transactionManagerRef = ConfigurationBD.NAME_TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
public class BDEncuesta {
    @Autowired
    private BDEncuestaConf bDEncuestaConf;

    @Bean(name = BDEncuestaConf.NAME_DATA_SOURCE)
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean(name = BDEncuestaConf.NAME_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY)
    @DependsOn(ConfigurationBD.NAME_TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
        return this.bDEncuestaConf.entityManagerFactory();
    }
}
```

ESTE ES LA CLASE BDEncuestaConf.java

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(BDEncuestaPro.class)
public class BDEncuestaConf {
    public static final String PREFIX_PROPERTIES = "adenbpo.datasource.reporte";
    public static final String NAME_DATA_SOURCE = "bdEncuestaDataSource";
    public static final String BASE_PACKAGES_ENTITYS = "com.adenbpo.encuestas.repository.entity";
    public static final String NAME_PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "bdEncuestaPersistenceUnit";
    public static final String BASE_PACKAGES_REPOSITORY = "com.adenbpo.encuestas.repository";
    public static final String NAME_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY = "bdEncuestaEntityManagerFactory";

    @Autowired
    private JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    @Autowired
    private BDEncuestaPro bDEncuestaProperties;

    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        return BDUtil.dataSource(bDEncuestaProperties, NAME_DATA_SOURCE);
    }
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
        return BDUtil.entityManagerFactory(bDEncuestaProperties, this.dataSource(),jpaVendorAdapter, BASE_PACKAGES_ENTITYS, NAME_PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
    }
}
```

CLASE BDEncuestaPro.java

```
import com.adenbpo.database.BDPro;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = BDEncuestaConf.PREFIX_PROPERTIES)
public class BDEncuestaPro implements BDPro{

    private String host;
    private String port;
    private String database;
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private int minPoolSize;
    private int poolSize;
    private int maxPoolSize;
    private String dialect;
    private String xadatasourceclassname;
    private String showsql;
    private String formatsql;

}
```

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código de la clase *BDEncuestaConf.java*?

Comment: Esta bien, pero masomenos sabes a que motivos es el error

Comment: Hay que ir mirando las cadenas de excepciones anidadas (que te aparecen como `Caused By`) para encontrar la excepción original y allí te dice: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adenbpo.conf.BDEncuestaConf`

Comment: Acabo de agregar la clase BDEncuestaConf.java

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adenbpo.conf.BDEncuestaConf En esa clase esta el error no conozco ese tipo de conexión a BD pero infiero que tus datos que van a la base están mal, corrobora con el debug que el dataSource se este generando bien de lo contrario te recomiendo subir el código a github para verlo bien y tal vez poderlo probar.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adenbpo.conf.BDEncuestaConf En esa clase esta el error no conozco ese tipo de conexión a BD pero infiero que tus datos que van a la base están mal, corrobora con el debug que el dataSource se este generando bien de lo contrario te recomiendo subir el código a github para verlo bien y tal vez poderlo probar.